# Chrome App Javascript: Save text as a DOCX file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I am aware that a DOCX file is essentially a zip full of XML files.  Is there any simple way of using the chrome.fileSystem storage API to save a DOCX file, or would I have to create and package the XML files manually?

```
chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({
    type: 'saveFile',
    accepts: [
        { extensions: ['docx'] },
        { extensions: ['txt'] },
    ]
}, function(writableFileEntry) {
    var ext = writableFileEntry.name.substr(writableFileEntry.name.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
    var text = document.getElementById("textarea").innerText;

    if(ext == 'docx'){
        ... ?
    }
    else if(ext == 'txt'){
        writableFileEntry.createWriter(function(writer) {
            writer.write(new Blob([text], {type: 'text/plain'}));
        }, function(){
             window.alert('Saving file failed');
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`fileSystem` API has nothing to do with specific file formats or compression - this is outside its scope. It's providing raw file access.

To do any kind of content formatting, you need to look for extra libraries or do it yourself, and then feed the resulting binary to `fileSystem`.